# Rate of flow problem

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, homework

> At time t = 0, a 1500-gallon tank contains 1000 gallons of old water. New water flows in at a rate of `g[t] == (K E^t)/(0.5 + E^t)` gallons/hour.
>   But water is pumped out at a rate of 80 gallons per hour.
>   Your job is to set the constant `K` so that the tank neither overflows nor runs dry for the next 100 days (= 2400 hours).​

I know that this question isn't a Mathematica specific one, but my class requires us to use Mathematica in order to solve this. I am having a tough time trying to understand how to find the solution.

Please help.

Comment: Please describe what you have tried so far.

Comment: I'm completely lost with this to be honest.

Answer (score 3):

```
g[t] := (k E^t)/(0.5 + E^t);
net0 = 1000; (*initial amount in the tank*)
net[t_, k_] = net0 + Integrate[g[t], t] - 80 t;
```

In order to find a `k` which doesn't overflow or dry out, we need to solve the equation at the extremum.

```
ku[t_] := 
 k /. Quiet@FindRoot[net[t, k] == 1500, {k, 1}, MaxIterations -> 100]
kd[t_] := 
 k /. Quiet@FindRoot[net[t, k] == 0, {k, 1}, MaxIterations -> 100]
```

Now, plot `ku[t]` and `kd[t]` to check the trend. It can be seen that the upper and limits seem to converge as `t` goes to 2400 hrs.

```
LogLinearPlot[{ku[t], kd[t]}, {t, 0, 2400}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

The extremum values of `k` at `t = 2400` are `{79.5, 80.2}`. So, the constant `k` should be in-between `(79.5, 80.2)` for the tank to neither overflow nor dry out.